# Sum sub query with condition

Tags: mysql

[image]

This is my data, the will be two `item = 0` data insert after `item = 10`, first of all, I need to filter `item = 0`

```
SELECT *
FROM `mega_wins` `a`
WHERE `item` != 0
```

And I got

[image]

My main goal is when met data item = 10, count next two data if expenditure > 300

```
SELECT *, IF (`a`.`ITEM` = 10,
    (
SELECT SUM(IF(`b`.`expenditure` > 500, 1, 0))
FROM `mega_wins` `b`
WHERE `b`.`id` > `a`.`id`
ORDER BY `b`.`id`
LIMIT 2)
, 0) `megaWin`
FROM `mega_wins` `a`
WHERE `item` != 0
```

But limit 2 seems failed, I got count by all data which is bigger the the item, how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: What order defines "next two?" Can you also share the expected results?

Comment: There will always have two `item = 0` datas followed `item = 10` data, I want to count it the followed `item = 0` data expenditure > 300, it should be `1, 6, 1000, 20000, 0`, `2, 10, 2000, 3000, 1`, `5, 6, 5000, 40000, 0`, `6, 10, 3000, 40000, 2`, `9, 6, 2000, 120000, 0`

Comment: so why not just add the condition to your where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your where the limit is not applying at all because you have an aggregate without a group by.. you cant have a group by because the subquery will return more than one row, which is invalid. What you need to do is add additional logic to your where in the subquery to account for the next two records. aka something like this

```
SELECT *, 
    IF (`a`.`ITEM` = 10,
    (   SELECT SUM(IF(`b`.`expenditure` > 500, 1, 0))
        FROM `mega_wins` `b`
        WHERE `b`.`id` > `a`.`id` and `b`.`id` - 2 <= `a`.`id` 
        ORDER BY `b`.`id`
    ), 0) `megaWin`
FROM `mega_wins` `a`
WHERE `item` != 0
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c14cac/1)

NOTE: this is a fairly bad query to run because it is running a correlated subquery on the table meaning `O(n^2)` which can be very taxing. it would be better to do this in another programming language after querying the database which you could do in straight linear time `O(n)`

Comment: @Chan, I would recommend doing this in another programming language. If the ids aren't continuous then there's nothing you can really do more in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility that only scans the table data once that only relies on the ids being sequential ascending, not necessarily incremented by 1.

```
select i id,
       max(item) item,
       max(income) income,
       max(if(item != 0,expenditure,null)) expenditure,
       sum(item = 0 and expenditure > 500) megaWin
from(
    select id, item, income, expenditure,
    case when rn = 0 then @id := id when rn in (1,2) then @id else id end i
    from(
        select id,
               item,
               income,
               expenditure,
               case when item = 10 then @rn := 0 when item = 0 then @rn := @rn + 1 end rn
        from mega_wins
        join (select @rn := null, @id := null) r
        order by id
    ) q
) q
group by i;
```

Comment: this is a bad solution because using UDF (user defined variables) in mysql has no promise of the order of operations... so there is the possibility that your assignment will happen in a random order.. which leads to invalid results [more details here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html)